# MISRA Violation Rule 15.5 : Multiple points of exit detected. Function should have a single point of exit at the end of the function

Tags: c, misra

I am trying to get rid of rule 15.5 from my code. This is basically because of multiple returns in the function.

Code looks like:

```
int32_t
do_test(int32_t array[])
{  
    for(int32_t i=0; i < VAL; i++)
    {
      if(array[i] == 2) {
        return 1;
      } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried with a temp variable which store the return value and returning this variable at the end. But that didnt work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You need to use a temp variable which stores the return value and return this variable at the end. Because that does work. If you don't do it wrong.

Comment: Could you show us your failed temp variable attempt?

Comment: int32_t
    do_test(const int8_t array[])
    {   
        int32_t temp;
        for(int32_t i=0; i < VAL; i++)
        {
          if(array[i] == 2) {
            temp = 1;
          } 
        }
    
        temp = 0;
    
        return temp;
    }  I tried like this. but here the for loop will execute completely and temp has the wrong value at the end

Comment: That's a rule that doesn't automatically enhance the reliability or readability of programs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler most of the misra rules make the code worse IMO

Comment: This is a defect in MISRA-C, see the linked duplicate. Basically it is garbage inherited from IEC 61508.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a temp variable *and* to break the loop

```
int32_t
do_test(int32_t array[])
{
    int32_t result = 0;  
    for(int32_t i=0; i < VAL; i++)
    {
      if(array[i] == 2) {
        result = 1;
        break; // !!
      } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Working fine. thanks !!!